# Weak topology compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, compactness

Let $X$ reflexive Banach and $X^*$ its dual space and consider the weak topology on $X$. We know that the weak topology is not metrizable in general (unless $X^*$ is separable as in the case of $L^2(\Omega)$).

So the compactness by coverings is not equal to the compactness by successions. Does this create problems in general in PDE's for example? In general I think in PDE's it much more used the compactness by successions for example to study the convergence of a sequence so I would say no. Am I right?

Anyway since $L^p$ are separable spaces except for $p=1, \infty$ then compactness by coverings is equavalent to the compactness by successions in $L^p$ except for $p=1, \infty$.

Comment: What do you mean by _compactness by successions_? In PDEs the first problem is to get any compactness, which in general is not possible for the weak topology (Banach-Alaoglu works for the weak-* topology).

Comment: By compactness by successions I mean: "Any sequence has a convergent subsequence". Yes I forgot to state the reflexivity hypothesis so that then the balls of $X$ are weakly compact

Comment: I added the reflexivity hypothesis

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Do you have a particular problem in mind or are you asking for examples and/or general arguments?

Comment: No I dont have any specific problem in mind, I'm asking for general arguments